# Divide phone and extension from phone number in two columns in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to divide extension and phone number in two columns?

For example:

```
416.977.7700 EXT 24
```

should be shown as:

```
Phone:     416.977.7700
Extension: EXT 24
```

Comment: Have the phone number the strict format (i.e. 3 num dot 3 num dot 4 num space EXT 2 num)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select left(phone, charindex(' EXT', phone + ' EXT')) as phone,
       substring(phone, charindex('EXT', phone + 'EXT'), len(phone))
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this solution

```
Declare @phone nvarchar(100) = '416.977.7700 EXT 24'
 select left(@phone, charindex(' ', @phone)-1) as phone,
  right(@phone,len(@phone) - charindex(' ', @phone)) extension
```